# The Merkle Tree library that I once used is giving this error even after installing it.. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mtree'

Tags: python, pip, merkle-tree

I used a library called 'mtree' in my research paper implementation. Now, when I try to import it it gives the following error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mtree'

I have tried to re-install it with pip install mtree. It gets installed without any issue, however I cannot use any of its functions. Can anyone please help?

One of the function of this library is mtree.create_tree('')

Comment: The package [mtree](https://pypi.org/project/mTree/) has nothing with Merkle Trees. See https://mtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conceptual_overview.html : mTree is a system for simulating and experimenting with Microeconomic Systems.

Comment: That one is with the capital T  (mTree), I have searched for it. But the mtree that I used had small t. Does anyone know any simple merkle tree library for python that I can use? I will have to change my complete code again

Comment: Regarding package names PyPI and `pip` are case-insensitive. `pip install mtree` installs said mTree.

Comment: "*Does anyone know any simple merkle tree library for python that I can use?*" https://pypi.org/search/?q=merkle